# How to set default selected menuItem in TVML?

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

Is there a way to set a menuItem which's order is not the first to be first view ?

jus like Youtube, they using MenubarTemplate and the first menuItem is search, but always shows the second one in first run.

I can setSelectedItem in code, but you still see the focus was on first one in a very short time, so can I set a default page which is not first of menuItem in TVML ?

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute `autoHighlight="true"` (https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH42-SW1). It's working in several templates, one of them being the Menu/Navigationbar - but some others seem to be buggy.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Achieve it by adding autoHighlight="true". For example <menuItem selectTargetURL="templates/page2.xml" autoHighlight="true">